# Ofdm and subcarrier modulation

Tags: ofdm

I was learning about OFDM systems and the different subcarriers. My understanding is thay each subcarrier carries one symbol. One question come to mind, can these different subcarriers be modulated differently for example one subcarrier with BPSK and another with QPSK?
What about SCFDMA?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's totally possible to have different modulation alphabets per subcarrier. You can do that, e.g. when different subcarriers experience different SNRs.